# Webstorm / PHPstorm switcher

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have a love-hate relationship with Webstorm (currently using 8.0.4).

One of the things I dislike is the fact that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcuts seem to use the most-recently-used tab order.

The other thing I dislike is that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut always switches to a non-source file tab (TODO, Favorite, Project structure tab...).

I've tried googling as well as configuring the "Switcher" component in the options, but it seems I can only change the shortcuts, not the actual behaviour.

Does anyone know how I could configure the Switcher component to my liking?

I can live with the MRU tab order, but I absolutely detest the non-source tabs in the tab order. How can I remove them from the Switcher list?

Comment: 1) **Quick** Ctrl+Tab (I'm on Windows) always switches to the most recent editor tab -- no idea about your *"least-recently-used tab order"* experience 2) I remember seeing no options for removing tool windows from the Switcher and could not find anything like that in the Registry screen.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write **most**-recently-used, not least-recently-used :/

Comment: OK. **1)** You cannot remove tool windows from there, full stop. **2)** Alt/Ctrl+Tab works in MRU order -- same as Alt+Tab on Windows (at least -- do not know about other OS). If MRU is not good enough -- maybe Ctrl+E (Recent Files) will do better? You can do quick search (typing) there to find file faster.

Comment: Alt+LeftArrow and Alt+RightArrow switch between tabs in their positional order - maybe try reassigning Ctrl+Tabs shortcut to those?

Comment: @ClementMandragora Excellent! I will do just that! LazyOne: I love Ctrl+E, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @LazyOne Can't thank you enough for Ctrl+E! I've spent last 30 minutes googling this. What were they thinking making tools to be selected by default in switcher?!